# Redirect Specific Mobile Traffic to Mobile Version Using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a PHP website about books that uses URL Rewriting rules already defined on my .htaccess file on my Apache Server, so due to the following rule I already have URLs like

http://www.example.com/book/name-of-book.html

```
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to improve my website and make a mobile version of it and I want to use URLs such as

http://m.example.com/book/name-of-book.html

As I am not completely done with mobile development I want only the book section to have a mobile version. So www.example.com would remain the same, but www.example.com/book/... would trigger the condition.

Which rules should I append to my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ http://m.example.com/m_book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L,R]

RewriteRule ^book/([^/]+)\.html$ book.php?book=$1 [QSA,L]
```

These horrible conditions in the first two lines will detect the mobile browsers by their User-Agent headers. The following rule will redirect queries to the mobile site.

The fourth line is needed to rewrite the paths for devices that are not moblie devices.

Comment: And what if the PHP file responsible to render the mobile version is a different one of the regular book.php, located in a different folder: /mobile/m_book.php?

Comment: That's not a problem - you just change the name of script on the third line (first RewriteRule). It would be `http://m.example.com/mobile/m_book.php?book=$1` or `http://m.example.com/m_book.php?book=$1` in your case - depending on your DocumentRoot and other options.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't nearly a complete solution, but it should point you in the right direction.

You first need to match a mobile user-agent, and it has to be on the host that isn't mobile (www.example.com). Then the rule itself should match against `/book`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?book/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/book/$1 [R,L]
```

The placement of these rules inside your htaccess will matter, so you may want to experiment with where you think this redirect should happen. It should take place *before* you translate the nice looking URLs to the `/book.php?book=name` URI's.

Comment: And what if the PHP file responsible to render the mobile version is a different one of the regular book.php, located in a different folder: /mobile/m_book.php?