# Buy Now button not opening mobile site on click

Tags: wordpress, paypal

Using a Buy Now button on a WordPress responsive site with the code below. When clicked on mobile, the desktop version of the PayPal check out page is presented. How can I correct my code snippet to redirect to the PayPal mobile site when the use is on a mobile device?

`<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&amp;hosted_button_id=XXXXXXX" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" alt="" />`

Comment: Once you click onto the href, you're off to another website where you have no control.  Do they provide you with a mobile url at all?

Comment: If you need to point to a mobile url when on a mobile, this may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775600/how-to-redirect-mobile-web-to-different-links